# CodeIgniter flashdata duration

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, session, google-analytics

I have a question on CodeIgniter flashdata duration. The problem is related to eCommerce and registering events via a Facebook Pixel and Google Analytics.

Currently I am using a variable, let's say for the example it's called

`$this->session->flashdata('purchase_total');`

So, when I arrive at the *'purchase-finished'* section, I have two events.

First event (in header view)

```
fbq('track', 'Purchase', {
    value: '<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('purchase_total'); ?>',
    currency: 'MXN'
});
```

Second event (in footer view)

```
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
    'id': '<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('id_purchase'); ?>',             
    'affiliation': 'Printome',
    'revenue': '<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('purchase_total'); ?>',
    'shipping': '<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('tracking_shipping'); ?>',
    'tax': '<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('tax'); ?>',
    'currency': 'MXN'
});
ga('ecommerce:send');
```

Now, the `purchase_total` gets registered correctly on Facebook, but on Analytics, the transaction gets registered, but without `purchase_total`.

I checked [CodeIgniter Session Library's Documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata), and it says that flashdata is available for one request and then cleared.

The thing is that in this case I am not sure if the request would be represented by calling `$this->session->flashdata('purchase_total')` or refreshing the page.

Comment: `flashdata` only available for one page load. It means if you refresh or redirect page, it will get cleared.  **Its an Temporary data storage methods**

Comment: So, if I call it twice in the same pageload, it should recover the correct data without any issues?

Comment: no issues you can use it. But if that page gone to another then it will not

Comment: @AbdullaNilam why did you edit CodeIgniter's to CodeIgniter ??

Comment: why what's the issue on that ?

Comment: It's not incorrect, it is CodeIgniter's flashdata. It's grammatically correct as far as I am concerned.

Answer (score 1):

> In your case I'll recommend to use `Tempdata` which can hold for limited time(Can set)

---

### FlashData

Can hold data until current page refresh/reload. Once that get moved to another page Flashdata get destroyed.  It can hold N number of time But destroyed when current page refreshed.

---

### Tempdata

This is something beyond the `FlashData`. This can hold data multiple redirects as well N number of time. But this is not like a session. It's act like session.

**Syntax** : `$this->session->mark_as_temp('item', 300);`

---

### Dif between `Tempdata` and `Flashdata`

```
       Flashdata                                               TempData
1. Short Time                                       Can hold for Bit long
2. automatically destroyed when page refreshed      Can hold until expiration time reaches
3. Page reload not allowed                          Can Reload or redirect 
4. Flashdata name and Value only required           Tempdata name, Value only and expiry time Required
```

---

### Links

1. [Tempdata - codeigniter.com](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#tempdata)
2. [Flashdata- codeigniter.com](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata)

Comment: I don't really need it to remain after reload, that's why I used flashdata. I thought it was getting cleared after one usage, but it shows normally. I did a test purchase to display the data I use and I got this as a result:
``fbq('track', 'Purchase', {
   value: '247.2',
   currency: 'MXN'
  });


  ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
   'id': '58',             
   'affiliation': 'Printome',
   'revenue': '247.2',
   'shipping': '99',
   'tax': '39.552',
   'currency': 'MXN'
  });
  ga('ecommerce:send');``

Comment: The problem is that my Google Analytics doesn't register those numbers, I am not sure if there's a problem with the decimals, or some issue with the amounts. It registers the transaction, but not the revenue.

Comment: I still haven't found what was causing it, but it's working at the moment @Abdulla Nilam